# Cycling through powers of a generator of finite field. Something similar to modpow for Z/nZ

Tags: finite-groups, finite-fields, exponentiation, cyclic-groups

I am not sure if I am talking to the correct community (perhaps stack overflow is best).  I want to be able to compute $$g^x = \underbrace{g \cdot g \cdot \dots \cdot g}_\text{x amount of times}$$ really fast, where $g \in GF\left(2^m \right)$.

Here m is rather large, $m = 256$, $384$, $512$, etc.  so lookup tables are not the solution.  I know that there are really fast algorithms for a similar idea, modpow for $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ (see page 619-620 of [HAC](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/about/chap14.pdf)).

1. What is a fast, non-table based way to compute cycles (i.e. $g^x$)?
2. This is definitely a wishful question but here it comes: Can the idea of montgomery multiplication/exponention be 'recycled' to galois fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binary exponentiation, aka *square and multiply* is the way to go. A possibility that comes to mind is to use a suitable [normal basis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_basis) to represent the elements of $GF(2^n)$. The reason is that then squaring becomes a very cheap operation. It is equivalent to cyclically shifting the coordinate bits.

To optimize the multiplication you want to use such a normal basis that the products of the basis elements can be written as sums of as few basis elements as possible. Your set of values for $m$ is probably not too nice in the sense that so called *optimal normal bases* probably won't exist for any of thos. Anyway, IIRC the Handbook of Cryptography has an algorithm for finding a reasonably good normal basis.

If your application insists on using a monomial basis for the field in question, then you 
need to write a routine for changing from one basis to another.

Comment: The algorithms I have looked at to use square and multiply, square and multiply using montgomery multiplication[[1](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/103205/c14expgf.pdf) , [2](http://www.csd.uwo.ca/~eschost/Exam/Koc.pdf) ], and the normal bases [multiplication](http://www.shoup.net/papers/pow.pdf).

hopefully, I will implement these and release my code to the public later on this year or next year.

Comment: Thank you for your help and input on the subject matter.

Comment: @torrho: Do you public your implementation. I am working in GF2 and I would like to use your method

Comment: @mjohn1282 review the handbook of applied cryptography's Chapter 14 for pseudocode.  http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/about/chap14.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Pick a [primitive polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_polynomial_(field_theory)) and use [binary exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) together with repeated use of the Euclidean algorithm to reduce modulo your primitive polynomial.

Montgomery multiplication should generalize just fine.

Comment: is there a nice way to make that binary exponentiation into an iterative method?

Comment: I don't know. I'm not the right person to ask this kind of question, really.

Comment: @torrho: Isn't *square and multiply* an iterative method?

Comment: the way wikipedia defined squaring and multiplying was recursive. However any recursive method can be made iterative. so I suppose the answer is yes.  On second look of the definition, it shouldn't be too hard to turn the wiki definition to a recursive one.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan♦ thank you for your help and input on the subject matter